# how to fetch all dates for products from diff-diff time frame in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table where i have max_date and min_date for diff-diff products.

```
min_date    max_date    product
10/2/2019   5/26/2020   pencil
1/19/2017   7/10/2019   pen
5/17/2019   10/10/2020  paper
1/1/2018    6/15/2020   Books
```

now i need all dates between given time-frame for particular products like

Desired data

```
product date
pencil  2020-15-04
pen      1/1/2018
 paper  5/10/2019
Books   6/15/2020
pen     1/16/2019
paper   8/6/2020
pencil  1/13/2020
pencil  5/26/2020
Books   12/12/2019
Pen     1/6/2019
paper   1/22/2020
```

timeframe table have three cols: min_date, max_date and product prod table have dates, product. i need all date for pencil between min_date max_date 10/2/2019 5/26/2020

1. col A & B have dates range for products
2. we need all dates within the range

```sql
select P.dates,
       d.product
from prod p
     join timeframe d on p.product = d.product
```

Comment: I've gone ahead and just removed all the tags apart from [[tag:sql]] as they were a complete mess.

Comment: what are the data in your timeframe table?

Comment: Hey, i have edit it correctly

Comment: @kirtichoudhary we still don't have all the sample data we need, nor an explanation. You have more [edit]ing to do.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, i have edit again, 
1.col A & col B have dates range for products
2.we need all dates within the range

Comment: So, again, where is the data from the table `timeframe`? Also, why are you dates different formats in your expect results? That implies you aren't using a `date` but a `varchar`, a ***huge*** flaw.

Comment: timeframe table have three cols: min_date, max_date and product 
prod table have dates, product.

i need all date for pencil between min_date max_date
10/2/2019 5/26/2020


suppose- we have      

Format for dates can be anything,

Answer (score 1):

wild guess .....

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists timeframe
drop table if exists products

CREATE TABLE timeframe(
   min_date DATE  NOT NULL 
  ,max_date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,product  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO timeframe(min_date,max_date,product) VALUES
 ('10/2/2019','5/26/2020','pencil'),('1/19/2017','7/10/2019','pen')
,('5/17/2019','10/10/2020','paper'),('1/1/2018','6/15/2020','Books');

select * from timeframe

CREATE TABLE products(
   product VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL 
  ,date    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO products(product,date) VALUES
 ('pencil','2020-15-04'),('pen','1/1/2018'),('paper','5/10/2019')
,('Books','6/15/2020'),('pen','1/16/2019'),('paper','8/6/2020')
,('pencil','1/13/2020'),('pencil','5/26/2020'),('Books','12/12/2019')
,('Pen','1/6/2019'),('paper','1/22/2020')
-- rows that should not show in results below ??
,('pencil','1/13/2012'),('pencil','5/26/2012'),('Books','12/12/2012')
;

select *,
TRY_CONVERT(date,p.date) date2
from products p

SELECT   p.product, p.date
FROM      products AS p INNER JOIN
                timeframe AS t ON p.product = t.product 
                AND TRY_CONVERT(date,p.date) >= t.min_date 
                AND TRY_CONVERT(date,p.date) <= t.max_date
```